# Automatically create Item in reverse foreign table if not exist in django rest frameworks

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I've model as shown below.

```
class Estimate(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.CompanyInfo,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='company'
    )
```

and the company model is

```
class CompanyInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), max_length=254)
    address = models.CharField(_("Address"), max_length=255)
```

If I follow documentation as suggested [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

I can able to create foreign table data, but I want this in reverse order.

Let me clarify more.
Suppose the user wants to create a new estimate object. each time user creates a new object user is also providing all the information which is required to create company info. I hope this sentence makes some sense.

Now my requirement is if the company already exists, I just want to use company id in the estimate table, otherwise, create a new company and assign its id for a new estimate object.

Also, I'm not sure either this is possible or not so I'm really sorry for this stupid question.